# SUDO NOPASSWD not working on a specific command

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

I have a tricky situation. 
I need a user `nagios` to execute a specific command as another user `jenkins` -- However this command only works if the `jenkins` environment is fully loaded. Otherwise the command I'm running won't work, so I need to do a `su - user` type command.

**Command works fine when ran from root:**

```
/bin/su - -c "pm2 show proxy" jenkins
```

(I get the expected output)

**When ran from nagios user:**

```
nagios@srv01:~$ sudo /bin/su -c "pm2 show proxy" jenkins
[sudo] password for nagios:
```

**visudo entries I've tried:**

```
nagios  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - -c "pm2 show proxy" jenkins

nagios  ALL=(jenkins) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - -c "pm2 show proxy" jenkins
```

Neither of the above work, it still asks for password.

**IT WORKS if I simply grant `nagios` user full `su` permissions:**

`nagios  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/su`

^^ this works, but NO, not granting full su permissions to this user.

Since it works when globally allowing `su` I'm assuming it's somewhere in my syntax.

**Edit -** In order to get around this issue I just put the command I want to run in a script and granted sudo to the script. However this is not ideal and adds an extra step in this workflow. Would much rather be able to run the command directly with sudo.

Comment: Can you try something like `sudo -u jenkins -s ...`

Comment: Thanks but pm2 is picky -- I need to load the full user environment in order to run the pm2 command since it loads the path from environment. so, for example  `sudo -u jenkins -s whoami` works fine but `sudo -u jenkins -s pm2` just results in `/bin/bash: pm2: command not found` because it didn't load jenkins environment as is done with `su - jenkins`

Comment: @emmdee just specify the full path to pm2

Comment: I know this sounds weird but the full path to pm2 changes depending on the version of node.js that's active at the time. When the target user (jenkins in this case) loads its profile it updates the path for the pm2 alias. I'm going to toy with wildcards in visudo to see if it works with `*` in the path.

Comment: `nagios ALL=(jenkins) NOPASSWD: pm2 show Proxy` would be the sudoers entry for using sudo -i -u jenkins as nagios. However a possible simpler solution is to add the nagios ssh key into the Jenkins authorized keys file with a cmd= restriction, then you don’t need a sudo rule or nagios user at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the login environment for jenkins then try to use the `-i` switch to sudo

> -i [command]
>   The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed. sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell. The security policy shall initialize the environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what is present when a user logs in. The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.

So something like

```
sudo -u jenkins -i pm2 show proxy
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks - so what would the crontab entry look like?

The full path to pm2 changes depending on different conditions (depends on version of node.js that's active for the user which switches around)

Comment: Sorry I meant `visudo` not crontab, but it's too late to edit my comment :(

Comment: I can confirm that `sudo -u jenkins -i pm2 show proxy` works fine when ran from root, same as my original command posted. Same issue though it still asks for password when ran from `nagios` user. 

I've tried `nagios  ALL=(jenkins) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo` and `nagios  ALL=(jenkins) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u jenkins -i pm2 show proxy` and `nagios  ALL=(jenkins) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u jenkins -i pm2` and all of them still ask for password when running `sudo -u jenkins -i pm2 show proxy` as the nagios user.

Comment: @emmdee Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @emmdee You don't call sudo twice! The sudoers file should just have `pm2 show proxy`, not an extra su or sudo.

Comment: I think `pm2` executable should be included in the sudoers file via full path. First, figure out the path of `pm2` via `/bin/su - -c "which pm2" jenkins`. Then, update the sudoers file with `visudo`. Eg. `nagios  ALL=(jenkins) NOPASSWD: /home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3/bin/pm2 show proxy`. Finally, use the original sudo command that will be resolved to full path as per `jenkins` user's `PATH`. Eg. `sudo -i -u jenkins pm2 show proxy`

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you can use python pudo package: https://pypi.org/project/pudo

Installation:

```
user$ sudo -H pip3 install pudo # you can install using pip2 also
```

Below is the code snippit for using in python automation for running cmds under root privilege::

```
user$ python3 # or python2
>>> import pudo
>>> (ret, out) = pudo.run(('ls', '/root')) # or pudo.run('ls /root')
>>> print(ret)
>>> 0
>>> print(out)
>>> b'Desktop\nDownloads\nPictures\nMusic\n'
```

Below is the cmd example for running cmds under root privilege

```
user$ pudo ls /root
Desktop  Downloads  Pictures  Music
```

Answer (score 1):

Some complicated commands don't work in sudoers files, or at least I've never succeeded.  For something complex, I put the command in a shell script and allow that in the sudoers file.

This way I'm less likely to get something obscure wrong with sudo syntax (which can lead to exploits) and the next admin can figure out what's going on quickly (perhaps without the sudo manpage).

Comment: Ok, it sounds like that could potentially be exploited by editing the script. However I guess if you just give it "execute" permissions only it might be ok. Thanks for the advice.